# ERROR: dependency ‘cowplot’ is not available for package ‘ggpubr’

Tags: ggplot2, rstudio, weibull, ggpubr

I tried to install the package ggpubr in Rstudio. Unfortunately, it got the following message "ERROR: dependency ‘cowplot’ is not available for package ‘ggpubr’"

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I am using Rstudio version 1.1.419 on mac

Comment: Hi! Did you try to `install.packages("cowplot")`? Normally this should be installed, when you select to install also dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I already found the problem: I needed to update my R. Package was not running on the current version.